# How to retrieve My Quick Links on Sharepoint using Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, silverlight

I need to retrieve the List of the Current User's "My Quick Links" on my Silverlight Application from SharePoint 2010 using the Client Object Model.

Could someone please advice on how this can be acheived using Client Object Model?

Answer (score 0):

you have to give a call to MyQuickLinks.aspx (full URL would be {URL of My Site Host}/_layouts/MyQuickLinks.aspx)

have to write script to pull data from it.